# Bigquery return nested results without flattening it without using a table

Tags: google-bigquery

It is possible to return nested results(`RECORD` type) if `noflatten_results` flag is specified but it is possible to just view them on screen without writing it to table first.

for example, here is an simple `user` table(my actual table is big large(400+col with multi-level of nesting)

```
ID,
name: {first, last}
```

I want to view record particular user & display in my applicable, so my query is

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.user WHERE id=423421 limit 1
```

is it possible to return the result directly?

Comment: what happens when you run the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your output to "temp" table with noflatten_results option (also respective expiration to be set to purge table after it is used) and serve your client out of this temp table. All "on-fly"
Have in mind that no matter how small "temp" table is  - if you will be querying it (in above second step) you will be billed for at least 10MB, so you better use Tabledata.list API in this step (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list) which is free!

Answer (score 0):

So if you try to get repeated records it will fail on the interface/BQ console with the error:

```
Error: Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time.
```

and in order to get past this error is to FLATTEN your output.